# DataTables: "targets: - 1` Meaning?

Tags: datatables

In this datatables [example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html), what's the meaning of `targets : -1`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/arrays.txt",
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>"
        } ]
    } );

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        alert( data[0] +"'s salary is: "+ data[ 5 ] );
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in the [Documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) :

`Targets` tells DataTables which column(s) the definition (`columnDefs`) should be applied to. It may be :

- 0 or a positive integer - column index counting from the left
- A negative integer - column index counting from the right
- A string - class name will be matched on the TH for the column
- The string "_all" - all columns (i.e. assign a default)

So `-1` is the first column counting from the right.